# Rate of change of stock price in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing columns describing the following entities:

I) Stock Symbol,
II) Timestamp,
III) Price.

For each stock symbol, I’d like to find the discrete change in price defined by the current price minus the price from the closest but previous entry, divided by the current time minus the previous entries time.

For example, let’s say I have:
…
(AAPL, 10, 100)
(AAPL, 12, 101)
…

Here, we have two rows for AAPL. At time 10, the price is 100, and at time 12, the price is 101. Suppose these are the only entries for AAPL in the data frame. I would like to add a fourth column that would be

…
(AAPL, 10, 100, NaN)
(AAPL, 12, 101, (101-100)/(12-10))
…

The first rows entry is NaN because there’s no AAPL before it. The second is the rate of change of the price based on the closest previous entry we have.

If all of the stock symbols were the same, I could just sort by timestamp and compute the discrete changes by looking at successive rows. However, it’s possible that there are different symbols. I wouldn’t want AAPL to get matched to anything but AAPL.

Can someone please help me achieve this behavior? I did some research, and the merge_as of function seems relevant. I can’t quite get the parameters right though, and I’m not even sure if it’s the correct approach.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Could you show like 10 rows of your data, at least the time series distribution?

Comment: I added some more detail. I’ll add more data and make a more comprehensive example soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start out with this data for example:

```
   stock  time       price
0      A     7  101.666400
1      A    15  101.577825
2      A    20  102.686615
3      A    21  101.869665
4      A    24  100.941477
5      A    25  101.777495
6      A    30  102.926569
7      A    33   99.433201
8      A    42  102.197779
9      A    44   99.671157
10     B     2   49.742638
11     B     7   48.775407
12     B    14   47.568738
13     B    16   50.237352
14     B    23   47.766212
15     B    28   47.838829
16     B    29   47.431216
17     B    32   46.286115
18     B    36   43.962685
19     B    41   44.047109
```

Then you could do the following:

```
df_roc = df.assign(
    roc=df.groupby('stock').apply(lambda x: x['price'].diff()/x['time'].diff()).droplevel(0)
)

print(df_roc)
```

**Result with rate-of-change**

```
   stock  time       price       roc
0      A     7  101.666400       NaN
1      A    15  101.577825 -0.011072
2      A    20  102.686615  0.221758
3      A    21  101.869665 -0.816950
4      A    24  100.941477 -0.309396
5      A    25  101.777495  0.836018
6      A    30  102.926569  0.229815
7      A    33   99.433201 -1.164456
8      A    42  102.197779  0.307175
9      A    44   99.671157 -1.263311
10     B     2   49.742638       NaN
11     B     7   48.775407 -0.193446
12     B    14   47.568738 -0.172381
13     B    16   50.237352  1.334307
14     B    23   47.766212 -0.353020
15     B    28   47.838829  0.014523
16     B    29   47.431216 -0.407613
17     B    32   46.286115 -0.381700
18     B    36   43.962685 -0.580857
19     B    41   44.047109  0.016885
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the perfect and fast way to do it , but it will work with you

Suppose this is your df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['AAPL', 10, 100],
                   ['AAPL', 12, 101],
                   ['AAPL', 14, 106]])
```

so it will look like this

```
df
       0    1   2
0   AAPL    10  100
1   AAPL    12  101
2   AAPL    14  106
```

your fourth column will be

```
col4 = (df[2][1:].values - df[2][:-1].values) 

col4 = col4 / (df[1][1:].values - df[1][:-1].values)

col4 = pd.Series([np.nan]).append(pd.Series(col4))
col4 = col4.reset_index(drop=True)
```

so it will apear like

```
col4
0    NaN
1    0.5
2    2.5
dtype: float64
```

now you can do

```
df[3] = col4
```

so your data frame will be

```
df
       0    1   2   3
0   AAPL    10  100 NaN
1   AAPL    12  101 0.5
2   AAPL    14  106 2.5
```

and that what we want, I think!

Comment: The output for the provided example is correct, but I think the answer makes the implicit assumption that all of the symbols are the same. For example, if I add an entry for MSFT, I wouldn’t want AAPL ever getting matched to MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `.diff()` method which you can use on series objects.

You can probably do something like:

```py
price.diff() / timestamp.diff()
```

Comment: But I want the symbols to be the same. If I sort by timestamp, this would work correctly if there’s just one symbol. If I naively do what you said, it can be the case that we end up subtracting two values with different symbols.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case I would probably extract into separate dataframes first - one for every symbol - and once you've done the calculations you could join them together again.

Comment: Is there an easy way to separate by symbol and merge again? I’m completely new to pandas. The way I would do it is just make a set of symbols, iterate over each symbol while using Boolean indexing, compute a diff, and append it to an array. Finally I would use pd.concat to merge. Is this inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without `apply()`

given time series data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df
###
              Datetime Symbol       Price
0  2022-07-12 12:00:00   AAPL  147.795700
1  2022-07-12 12:02:00   AAPL  147.705002
2  2022-07-12 12:02:00   NVDA  152.940002
3  2022-07-12 12:03:00   AAPL  147.694595
4  2022-07-12 12:03:00   NVDA  153.009995
5  2022-07-12 12:08:00   NVDA  152.763504
6  2022-07-12 12:09:00   AAPL  147.419998
7  2022-07-12 12:11:00   AAPL  147.419998
8  2022-07-12 12:20:00   NVDA  152.869995
9  2022-07-13 11:24:00   NVDA  152.294998
10 2022-07-13 11:25:00   NVDA  151.910095
```

price delta

```
price_d = df.groupby('Symbol')['Price'].diff()
```

time delta in minute

```
time_d = df.groupby('Symbol')['Datetime'].diff()/ np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

`/ np.timedelta64(1,'m')` turns the time delta unit into **minute**

Result

```
df['diff'] = price_d/time_d
df
###
              Datetime Symbol       Price      diff
0  2022-07-12 12:00:00   AAPL  147.795700       NaN
1  2022-07-12 12:02:00   AAPL  147.705002 -0.045349
2  2022-07-12 12:02:00   NVDA  152.940002       NaN
3  2022-07-12 12:03:00   AAPL  147.694595 -0.010406
4  2022-07-12 12:03:00   NVDA  153.009995  0.069992
5  2022-07-12 12:08:00   NVDA  152.763504 -0.049298
6  2022-07-12 12:09:00   AAPL  147.419998 -0.045766
7  2022-07-12 12:11:00   AAPL  147.419998  0.000000
8  2022-07-12 12:20:00   NVDA  152.869995  0.008874
9  2022-07-13 11:24:00   NVDA  152.294998 -0.000415
10 2022-07-13 11:25:00   NVDA  151.910095 -0.384903
```